# Is there some way to attract more verticies to certain parts of a models

Tags: vertices, displacement, 3d-printing

I Have an object with properly set up uvs and im using a displacement map to make some detailed cracks on it. My problem is that the geometry is equally distributed on the model and i only need the detail along the cracks so they look cleaner so i can 3d print it. What i have to do right now is add a sub modifier to the point where my mesh reaches 8 million faces which is not ideal because my pc isnt strong enough to unsub it later.

Is there any way i can procedurally concentrate vertices along these cracks using maybe the displacement map in some way or some other way?

1st image is my displacement
2nd the mesh im trying to apply it to

[image: This is my displacement map btw. It is quite detailed]

[image: And this is the mesh im trying to apply it to]